# Recurrent Neural Models with Multiple Individuals/Ids

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm fairly beginner in the world of machine learning and am trying to make some predictions on fantasy sport performance in baseball on any given night. Given the sequential nature of the data, recurrent neural networks seemed liked a good starting point.

I understand the basic principles of rnn but what isn't clear to mean is how to incorporate multiple time series' from different individuals into a single model. For instance, we have performance for 2000 players across each of their career and hence have 2000 distinct time series. In order to make use of rnn, would I have to build models for each player separately, or is it possible/better to pass a player's ID into the model as a feature?

If the latter is possible, I'm still unsure about how this would mechanically work, because players have different time series lengths, and we would have many time series observations for a particular point in time.

Some references/examples/advice would be very helpful.

Comment: This is a pretty complex question. You are correct that the data is in a sequential nature (in that a player has stats over a career/season), but the main question is if that sequence is dependant on previous instances and I would argue that it is not. The notion that a batter will have certain results tomorrow based on the previous x games is simply not true (look up the [Gambler's Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy). So I'm not convinced you have a RNN problem here.

Comment: @chitown88 I agree that observations being related across time is potentially not as strong as say, a stock price would be. But I think there is a 'streakiness' component as well. At the same time, there is a non tme series component which arguably matters more, which is all the other factors: the pitcher they face, the ballpark they are playing in, etc..

Comment: Yes the other factors you mention (as well as others like how often they hit with men on base/RISP, they're slugging %) are what you want to probably focus on. The "streakiness" component is precisely the Gambler's Fallacy that I am alluding to. Give [this](https://medium.com/the-sports-scientist/are-hot-and-cold-streaks-real-in-baseball-10530c582932#:~:text=Now%2C%20to%20clarify%20%E2%80%94%20of%20course,over%20a%20few%20days%20span.&text=If%20a%20player%20is%20crushing,so%20in%20next%20five%20games.) a read as well.

Comment: This tutorial will give you some insights on Timeseries data and RNN model https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series